# Missing assembly reference SqlCeSyncProvider C#

Tags: c#, .net, reference, .net-assembly, using

I'm trying to use  `SqlCeSyncProvider` in synchronization code but it gives the error `SqlCeSyncProvider dos not exist, Are you missing assembly reference`. On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.synchronization.data.sqlserverce.sqlcesyncprovider%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) its given than `SqlCeSyncProvider` is available in `Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe` assembly  I tried `using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe;` but it ended with no sucess.

I tried 2.0.0.0 ,3.1.0.0 and 3.5.0.0 version of assembly but don't understand what can be the problem. I also tried using `using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeSyncProvider;` but it gives error

```
The type or namespace name 'SqlCeSyncProvider' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Does it mean the Microsoft doc is wrong?

Complete code example

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Synchronization;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe;

namespace ExecuteExpressSync
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection clientConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=SyncExpressDB; Trusted_Connection=Yes");

        SqlConnection serverConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=SyncDB; Integrated Security=True");

        // create the sync orhcestrator
        SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();

        // set local provider of orchestrator to a sync provider associated with the 
        // ProductsScope in the SyncExpressDB express client database
        syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("ProductsScope", clientConn);

        // set the remote provider of orchestrator to a server sync provider associated with
        // the ProductsScope in the SyncDB server database
        syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("ProductsScope", serverConn);

        // set the direction of sync session to Upload and Download
        syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;

        // subscribe for errors that occur when applying changes to the client
        ((SqlCeSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(Program_ApplyChangeFailed); // Error on this line

        // execute the synchronization process
        SyncOperationStatistics syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();

        // print statistics
        Console.WriteLine("Start Time: " + syncStats.SyncStartTime);
        Console.WriteLine("Total Changes Uploaded: " + syncStats.UploadChangesTotal);
        Console.WriteLine("Total Changes Downloaded: " + syncStats.DownloadChangesTotal);
        Console.WriteLine("Complete Time: " + syncStats.SyncEndTime);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);
    }

    static void Program_ApplyChangeFailed(object sender, DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        // display conflict type
        Console.WriteLine(e.Conflict.Type);

        // display error message 
        Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Did you add reference to `Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` or not?

Comment: yes I had added reference that's why it don't give error on using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe .

Comment: Do you have x64 or x86 version of sync SDK? What is the target platform of your project?

Comment: target platform is any cpu, and x64 sync SDK.

Comment: Can you change target platform to x64?

Comment: Tried but it doesn't help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51567/discussion-between-hot-cool-stud-and-ulugbek-umirov)